# How does the Sin and Cos scale on a slide rule work and what is the formula for it?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

As I described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194120/how-can-i-make-a-slide-rule-in-tikz), I am trying to make a printable slide rule (similar to the slide rule provided in [this SciAm article](http://www.uvm.edu/~pdodds/teaching/courses/2009-08UVM-300/docs/others/2006/stoll2006a.pdf)). I have made most of the parts of it but I can't make the Sin and the Cos scales. Although it looks very easy when I use a slide rule, but for some reason now I can't make them work. I tried various formulas but it didn't work.

From the original answer, I got the formula for the main log scale:
$$f(x,y)=(\log x)\cdot y$$
(where $f$ is the distance where the ticks have to be made, $x,y$ are integers and $y$ is fixed.)

But what is the formula for the $\sin$ and $\cos$ scales?

I searched on google but I didn't get any result.

If I diectly apply $\sin$, then I get this:

[image: wrong sin scale]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the $S$ scale is exactly the sine of the $C$ scale , where the argument is taken in *degrees*.  Say the length of the rule is $\ell $. Each point on the $C$ scale at distance $x$ from the index is marked with the number  $10^{2x/\ell }$.

Then each point on $S$ is marked with $$\sin\left (\frac\pi{180} 10^{2x/\ell}\right).$$

To use it, you have some argument on the $C$ scale of which you need to find the sine. You zero the scale (aligning the index marks) and match the cursor to the argument on the $C$ scale.
 Then you read the sine off of the corresponding value on the $S$ scale.

(To solve the reverse problem, "where on the $S$ scale should I place the label $s$?, you must invert this function: place label $s$ at distance $\frac\ell2\log\left (\frac {180}\pi\sin^{-1} s \right)$.)

---

**Addendum**: I think the foregoing would work well, but when I inspected an actual slide rule, I found that it was constructed differently: The $S$ scale, not the $A$ scale, is the argument.  I don't know if my memory was completely at fault or if different slide rules worked in different ways.   On the example slide rule I looked at, the argument (in degrees) is marked on the $S$ scale, for arguments between $\sin^{-1}\frac1{10}\approx 5.73^\circ$ and $\sin^{-1} 1 = 90^\circ$, and then the sines of these arguments are in the corresponding positions on the $D$ scale, which runs from $\frac1{10}$ to $1$.  For this slide rule, the rule is that each point at position $x$ is marked with the two labels  $\frac{180}\pi\sin^{-1}10^{(x/\ell)-1}$ and $90-\frac{180}\pi\sin^{-1}10^{(x/\ell)-1}$.

The picture below shows that the sine of $10^\circ10' $ (on the $S$ scale) is $0.1765 $ (on the $D$ scale).

[image: slide rule photo]

Comment: Thanks. I just forgot that computers work in radians.

Comment: Since the $C$ scale goes from 1 to 100, you conveniently get the $S$ scale from (almost) 0 to (a little more than) 1, and the important values close to 0 are well-represented.

Comment: Should the last formula not be $\frac{\ell}{2}\log(\sin^{-1}(\frac{s\cdot180}{\pi}))$?

Comment: No, of course not. The labels are sines of various angles, so are between $-1$ and $1$.   $\sin^{-1} x$ is defined only for $-1\le x\le 1$.  $\sin^{-1} \frac{180}\pi s$ is not even well-defined for labels in the range $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: “The picture below shows that the sine of $10.1^circ$ (on the $S$ scale) is $0.17537$ (on the $D$ scale).” Not quite. The photo shows that the sine of $10^\circ 10'$, or $10.17^\circ$ (note there are six, not ten, primary divisions between each degree on the $S$ scale), is about $0.1767$ (You seem to have misread the $D$ scale by one mark.)

Comment: @Steve You are absolutely right, thanks.